# Maven clean and package doesn't generate surefire reports

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project where module A/B/C depends on module D.
Plugin maven-surefire-plugin is used for test phrase.

However,

```
mvn clean package
```

doesn't generate surefire-reports under **/target/
And

```
mvn clean; mvn package
```

could generate surefire-reports as expected.

This confused me a lot. Although the workaround for me is simply splitting to two mvn commands but I would like to know why?

**Versions:**

- maven 3.3.3
- jdk 1.7.0
- maven-surefire-plugin 2.14

**Root Pom:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jzako.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>FeedbackSystem</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FeedbackSystem</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.21</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <modules>
        <module>ModuleA</module>
        <module>ModuleB</module>
        <module>ModuleC</module>
        <module>Utility</module>
  </modules>  
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 
</project>
```

**Module A Pom:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jzako.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>FeedbackSystem</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.jzako.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModuleA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ModuleA</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>   
                          <mainClass>org.jzako.test.main.LightweightFeedbackStatisticsMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assembly</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/../conf/dev</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${basedir}/../conf/dev</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jzako.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>Utility</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Multi-module Relationship**
Module A/B/C depends on Utility Module and no dependencies among Module A/B/C.

**Update:**
It seems everything's fine for a single maven module projects. Something related to the multi-modules?

Comment: For me it does work, could you show the relevant parts of your pom?

Comment: @pietv8x Yes I have attached part of the root pom file.

Comment: First full pom file and not only excerpts otherwise it's hard to help. Furthermore if you more information in relationship with multi module build you should show an example of that...I can't recreate the issue....

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your remind. More explanation added.

Comment: Do you have code in your parent `FeedbackSystem` which does not make sense.

Comment: @khmarbaise parent FeedbackSystem contains no code, only pom file and several modules.